# connect to mysql server from none localhost

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I wanna connect to mysql database from not localhost server.
but I can't do it.

I google and find I should edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf but mysql directory doesn't exist under etc directory.

under /etc directory only exist mysql_mmm and it contains following files.

```
mmm_agent.conf    mmm_mon.conf      mmm_tools.conf    
mmm_common.conf   mmm_mon_log.conf
```

now what should I do?

Comment: what distribution do you use? Anyway you can try "find / -name 'my.cnf'"

Comment: on which machine are you looking for the conf?

Comment: It found /etc/my.cnf but it doesn't contain bind-address

Comment: @Moein7tl : "I can't do it" : are you trying with a computer? ;) More seriously, please let us know any error message that you are getting. Did you confirm you can connect from the localhost?

Comment: @Moein7tl, add it to the [mysqld] section then.

Answer (score 1):

Check with PS -ef | grep mysql -->check for which  defaults-file it is using . you can edit that file to achive remote access by removing the bind address